# Error java.lang.nullpointerexception while creating new project in Zend studio

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I am getting a Error **java.lang.nullpointerexception** while creating new project using Zend studio.

I am using Zend Studio 9.0.1

I have used following steps:

File -> New -> Local Php Projects -> Add Project name, then click Next -> Click Finish.

[image]

Please suggest how can i resolve it.

Comment: What does it say when you click on the "Details" button?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. I believe this is an application error. `NullPointerException` is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required. Try to re-install / or fix it maybe (if there is such option)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall Zend studio then again with new installation its working fine.